# Error while processing print() in console

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here is some code on python 3 using Pandas, interpreter is 3.4.1

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.width', 300)
file = open('C:\PythonData\Result.csv', 'w')
file.write('"StopFirstIndex"' + ';' + '"StopLastIndex"' + ';' \
    + '"GOV_NUMBER"' + ';' + '"StopTime"' + '\n')
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:\PythonData\data4.csv', ",", header=0).sort_index(by=['CAR_ID', 'DATE_TO'])
df1.index = range(0, len(df1))
StopFirstIndex = 0
StopLastIndex = 0
CntZeroSpeedRows = 0
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['SPEED'] == df1.get_value(index + 1, 'SPEED') == 0 and row['CAR_ID'] == df1.get_value(index + 1, 'CAR_ID'):
        if CntZeroSpeedRows >= 1:
            CntZeroSpeedRows += 1
        else:
            CntZeroSpeedRows = 1
    else:
        if CntZeroSpeedRows >= 3:
            StopFirstIndex = index - CntZeroSpeedRows
            StopLastIndex = index
            StopTime = pd.to_datetime(df1.get_value(StopLastIndex, 'DATE_TO'), dayfirst=True) - \
                       pd.to_datetime(df1.get_value(StopFirstIndex, 'DATE_TO'), dayfirst=True)
            tempdf1 = pd.concat([df1[StopFirstIndex:StopLastIndex+1]['LATITUDE'],
                                    df1[StopFirstIndex:StopLastIndex+1]['LONGITUDE']], axis=1)
            file.write('"' + str(StopFirstIndex) + '";"' + str(StopLastIndex) + '";"' \
                     + str(df1.get_value(StopFirstIndex, 'GOV_NUMBER')) + '";"' + str(StopTime) + '"' + '\n')  # making csv
            print(StopFirstIndex, StopLastIndex, df1.get_value(StopFirstIndex, 'GOV_NUMBER'), StopTime)  # printing results in console
        CntZeroSpeedRows = 0
file.close()
```

Making of the `csv` file is ok, but if I print results in console, after printing correct results, it shows me following error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):    
> File "C:/Users/Moiseev/PycharmProjects/untitled1/test1.py", line 21, in <module>
>    if row['SPEED'] == df1.get_value(index + 1, 'SPEED') == 0 and row['CAR_ID'] == df1.get_value(index + 1, 'CAR_ID'):    
> File "C:\Users\Moiseev\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1542, in get_value
return engine.get_value(series.values, index)    
File "index.pyx", line 97, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:2993)   
File "index.pyx", line 105, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:2808)    
File "index.pyx", line 149, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3534)    
File "hashtable.pyx", line 381, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:7035)    
File "hashtable.pyx", line 387, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:6976) KeyError: 1000

> Process finished with exit code 1
```

So, there is two questions:
    1. Is it critical?
    2. How can I remove this error?

Comment: `for index ...:  foo(index+1)` surely this won't work for the last row!

Comment: Yes, that't it, added first condition    if index < len(df1)-1:  and error is gone. Thanks @qarma!

Comment: Please post and accept an answer someone instead of editing "Answered" into the title. The robots that clean and prune StackOverflow will not understand this, and they will become confused and unhappy.